# Draw a Rectangle in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, gdi+

I try to write a class that will draw itself on a control(.NET **2**). But this "thing" does not repaint itself properly(does not invalidate the parent as it should).

Here is the usage:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim myCadre As New Cadre

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
      myCadre.Location = New Point(myCadre.Location.X + 1, myCadre.Location.Y + 1)
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next i
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myCadre.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    myCadre.Size = New Size(60, 90)
    myCadre.Parent = Me
  End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Cadre
  Private _Rectangle As Rectangle
  Private _Parent As Control
  Public Event ParentChanged As EventHandler
  Private _Location As Point

  Public ReadOnly Property DisplayRectangle() As Rectangle
    Get
      Return _Rectangle
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Property Location() As Point
    Get
      Return _Rectangle.Location
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Point)
      _Rectangle.Location = value
      DrawInternal()
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property Size() As Size
    Get
      Return _Rectangle.Size
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Size)
      _Rectangle.Size = value
      DrawInternal()
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property Parent() As Control
    Get
      Return _Parent
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Control)
      If _Parent IsNot value Then
        _Parent = value
        OnParentChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Overridable Sub OnParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    DrawInternal()
    RaiseEvent ParentChanged(sender, e)
  End Sub

  Private Sub DrawInternal()
    If _Parent Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim g As Graphics = _Parent.CreateGraphics()

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Me._Rectangle)
  End Sub
End Class
```

- What I am doing wrong?
- What is better: use `private Graphic g` and
  set it only once when parent changed,
  or create `g` at every
  `DrawInternal`?
- Is it possible to have on it the `Click` event?

## CADRE v2 (after Humberto suggestions):

```
Public Class Cadre
  Private _FormerRectangle As Rectangle
  Private _Rectangle As Rectangle
  Private WithEvents _Parent As Control
  Public Event ParentChanged As EventHandler
  Private _Location As Point

  Public Sub New()
    _FormerRectangle = New Rectangle
    _Rectangle = _FormerRectangle
  End Sub

  Private Sub DrawInternal(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles _Parent.Paint  
    If _FormerRectangle <> _Rectangle Then
      _Parent.Invalidate(_FormerRectangle, False) ' !!! does not work '
    End If

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Me._Rectangle)
    _FormerRectangle = Me._Rectangle
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property DisplayRectangle() As Rectangle
    Get
      Return _Rectangle
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Property Location() As Point
    Get
      Return _Rectangle.Location
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Point)
      _Rectangle.Location = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property Size() As Size
    Get
      Return _Rectangle.Size
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Size)
      _Rectangle.Size = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property Parent() As Control
    Get
      Return _Parent
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Control)
      If _Parent IsNot value Then
        _Parent = value
        OnParentChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Overridable Sub OnParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ParentChanged(sender, e)
  End Sub  

End Class
```

## Edit3

Location Example:

```
  Public Property Location() As Point
    Get
      Return _Rectangle.Location
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Point)
      If _Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        _Parent.Invalidate(_Rectangle, False) ' 1st Call with former '
      End If
      _Rectangle.Location = value
      If _Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        _Parent.Invalidate(_Rectangle, False) ' 2nd Call with new '
        _Parent.Update()
      End If
    End Set
  End Property
```

Does not work...

Comment: I think you're invalidating at the wrong time. Let the system call Paint() for you, and control the system through Parent.Invalidate() and Parent.Update(). Once this scenario is running, add functionality and test for performance.

Comment: @Humberto: So, where should I call Invalidate+Update?

Comment: Call them upon changes in the state of Cadre -- the `Location` and `Size` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook the `Cadre` class to the `Paint` event of the `_Parent` member:

```
Public Property Parent() As Control
    Get
      Return _Parent
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Control)
      If _Parent IsNot Nothing Then
          RemoveHandler _Parent.Paint, AddressOf Me.Cadre_Paint
      End If

      _Parent = value

      If _Parent IsNot Nothing Then
          AddHandler _Parent.Paint, AddressOf Me.Cadre_Paint
      End If
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Cadre_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Me._Rectangle)
End Sub
```

`Refresh()` the parent control upon `Cadre` changes on its location, size, contents etc.

```
Public Property Size() As Size
    Get
      Return _Rectangle.Size
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Size)
      _Rectangle.Size = value

      If _Parent IsNot Nothing Then
          _Parent.Refresh()
      End If
    End Set
End Property
```

---

The click event is handled in a similar manner. Add a handler for the _Parent.MouseDown event, and check if the mouse coordinates are inside your `Cadre`. Check [Control.MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) for more information.

Comment: what do you think about: `Private WithEvents _Parent As Control` and `Private Sub DrawInternal(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles _Parent.Paint`

Comment: I believe I should refresh on ly the former zone of the parent, not all the parent. Imagine there a million of Cadres is the parent that does not change... Is there such a posibility?

Comment: Refresh() causes an immediate repaint of the entire control. Invalidate() is asynchronous; it will *mark* the client area as ready for an update -- in fact, Control.Update() will synchronously paint the invalidated areas. For more information, check [Control.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) and [Control.Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: In this case, invalidate both the former and the current zone, then Update() the parent. It's more performance-wise.

Comment: ok, see my update, my idea would be to mark only the former rectangle and then Update(). But as you mention Update will however invalidate all the _Parent?!..

Comment: No. [Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) will trigger the repaint of the invalidated areas only.

Comment: see my Edit3, consecutive call of Invalidate on 2 region seems do not summ that regions for the Update...

Comment: I think I got the point, I forget the 1 px of rectangle border to include in the invalidating area!.. so, Size+(1,1)

Comment: The last thing: What about the `Click` event?

Comment: @serhio Increase the border, or use FillRectangle() to test. But I see a problem already -- the consecutive Invalidate() calls will draw two rectangles upon Update()! Also, did you add a handler for the _Parent.Paint event?